# How to allow zero(0) value

Tags: validation, go, go-echo

```
AgreementNo int`json:"agreement_no" validate:"required"`
```

I want get zero value from agreement_no request.
still required but get zero value so json request null not allow.
but validate in echo not allowed zero value.

How can I get this value without remove required validation
or there are any solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
AgreementNo int`json:"agreement_no" validate:"required"`
```

Validator cannot find the difference between default zero-value and 0 parsed from json, so it interpret all zero-values as empty. The same happens for boolean, strings, etc.

The workaround is to use pointer instead of plain type.

```
AgreementNo *int`json:"agreement_no" validate:"required"`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AgreementNo int`json:"agreement_no" default:"0"`
```

Replace the validate:"required" with default:"0"